# Select one or more values from an array based on binary value(s) from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. COLORS and STATUS (based on a binary string).

```
$binary_string = '001'; // Can be any combination of 0 and 1 (000,111,100,etc)
$colors = array('red','green','blue');
$status = str_split($binary_string);
```

I need to return the active/selected color(s) based on the string. In the example, I should get "blue".
What is the easiest way to achieve this in PHP? An example, please.

Thanks!

Comment: Loop over `$status`. If the current element is `1` then push the corresponding element of `$colors` into the result array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you need loop over `status` array which binary string representation of color if find `1` will set `color` to corresponding color in `RGB` and just exit the loop!

```php
<?php
$binary_string = '001';
$colors = array('red','green','blue');
$status = str_split($binary_string);

$color = '';
foreach ($status as $i => $bin) {
    if($bin==='1'){
        $color = $colors[$i];
        break;
    }
}
echo $color;//blue
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
<?php
$binary_string = '101'; // Can be any combination of 0 and 1 (000,111,100,etc)
$colors = array('red','green','blue');
$status = str_split($binary_string);
$final_colors = "";
for ($i=0; $i< 3; $i++) {
    SWITCH($i) {
        case 0:
         $final_colors .= $status[$i] ? 'red, ' : '';
         break;
        case 1:
         $final_colors .= $status[$i] ? 'green, ' : '';
         break;
        case 2:
         $final_colors .= $status[$i] ? 'blue' : '';
         break;
    }
}

echo $final_colors;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input J.T. Your code also works (had do change the case2 short if to blue).